# Windows Mobile & WCF Service on the IIS - Could not establish connection to network

Tags: wcf, iis-7, windows-mobile

I have set the WCF service on the IIS (localhost). I use that service in my application (windows mobile, C#). The problem is, when I try to invoke any method I see an error: **"Could not establish connection to network."** I deploy the application on the built-in emulator in the Visual Studio 2008 Professional. Why that error occurs ?

Comment: Are you seeing that error on the mobile device? If so, can it reach anything else over the network (Google, Yahoo, anything in a browser)?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to activate the network connectivity on the mobile device emulator. This might help: http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/Enable-Network-Connection-Windows-Mobile-6-Emulator.aspx

Or just Google around for enabling network on the windows mobile emulator...

Comment: So are we saying that this error is because the emulator has no internet connectivity (can't hit any website)? So it has nothing to do with WCF or IIS? If so, I would reword the question and re-tag it...